# delete nodes from the java AST of the Java code source

Tags: java, eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree, visitor-pattern

I want to change an AST Java by deleting the fully Qualified names and replace it by the corresponding imports.ça need to change the type of call completions nodes by simple nodes. The problem is that I can not find any function that allowed me to do. Who has an idea?
thank you in advance

Comment: are you using JDT to do so ?? place any code that you have written, that may give a better understanding.

Comment: thank's Unni Kris .Yes i use JDT

Answer (score 1):

This Eclipse Corner article on AST may help you - http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-JavaCodeManipulation_AST/index.html